# AndroidStudio: Display input field on click

Tags: android, android-studio

I am building an android app where a user can create, view, delete, and update his cooking recipes.

If a user is creating a recipe I want him to be able to add steps like: step1:, step2:, etc.
So if a user needs another step he simply tabs on a button "add step" and an input field should appear below the previous step.

I tried searching for this but didn't find anything. Could someone help me into the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following piece of code I am able to create new EditText fields on button click.

```
private int hint = 0;

public void addStep(View view) {
    //Get the linearLayout where the EditText fields will appear.
    LinearLayout container = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

    //Increment id by 1.
    hint++;

    //Create a new EditText field.
    EditText step = new EditText(this); //Creating new TextView

    //Add attributes to EditText
    step.setId(hint);
    step.setText("step");
    step.setMaxLines(1);
    step.setWidth(160);

    //Finally Display the EditText field in the LinearLayout
    container.addView(step);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are using constraintlayout

```
EditText step1 = findViewById(R.id.step1);
    EditText step2 = new EditText(this);
    step2.setId(R.id.step2);
    step2.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.parent);
    constraintLayout.addView(step2);
    constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);




    constraintSet.connect(step2.getId(),ConstraintSet.START,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.START,0);
    constraintSet.connect(step2.getId(),ConstraintSet.END,ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID,ConstraintSet.END,0);
    constraintSet.connect(step2.getId(),ConstraintSet.TOP,step1.getId(),ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,0);
    constraintSet.constrainWidth(R.id.step2,ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT);
    constraintSet.constrainHeight(R.id.step2,ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT);
    constraintSet.applyTo((ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.parent));
```

Comment: My app seems to crash when I tab the button.